# ActiveRecord Relation: append objects inside the ActiveRecord::Relation Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
#models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :partner_locations, ->{where(partner: true)}
    scope :education_locations, ->{where(education: true)}
end
```

Then I have the following code:

```
locations = Location.none
if true
  #append onto that locations activerecord::relation object those locations that are partner locations
  locations << Location.partner_locations
end
if true
  #append onto that locations activerecord::relation object those locations that are education locations
  locations << Location.education_locations
end
return locations
```

I would think that this code would return an activerecord::relation object with some objects inside of it.  Instead it just returns: `[]`, just an empty Location::ActiveRecord_Relation object.

How do I append records onto this Location::ActiveRecord_Relation object?

I did some research and I see some people suggest using `merge` but I don't think that is what I want.  I am not doing any filtering.  I only want to append on `Location` objects inside that Location::ActiveRecord_Relation object so that I can then use other methods on it like: `locations.order(:name)`.

Comment: Can you place a debugger or binding and verify what the output of Location.partner_locations and Location.education_locations?  Also can you post the rest of the code(like the parent method) for locations = Location.none
if true .....

Comment: [`.none`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none) seems to ensure that nothing gets returned. You might use a different base scope, and only append none if no other condition is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has a better way of doing this I would love to know.

I got it to do what I wanted to do by appending to a regular array, and then before returning it, I transformed it into an activerecord::relation so that I could use activerecord methods on it.  It would be nice If I could do the whole thing with the same activerecord::object:

```
locations = []
if true
  #append onto that locations array all the location objects that are partner locations
  locations = locations + Location.partner_locations
end
if true
  #append onto that locations array all those location objects those locations that are education locations
  locations = locations + Location.education_locations
end
return Location.where(id: locations.map(&:id)).order(:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@locations = Location.order(:name)
@locations = @locations.partner_locations if # what ever logic 
@locations = @locations. education_locations if # what ever logic 
@locations
```